# Can ACT students get NSW concession Opal card in Australia?

Tags: sydney

For a student who is studying at Australian Capital Territory (ACT), will it be possible to apply for New South Wales (NSW) concession Opal card to travel in Sydney?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, they can.  See below for the full list of approved institutions, which includes ACT-based schools like UC, ANU and CIT.

https://transportnsw.info/tickets-opal/ticket-eligibility-concessions/child-student-concessions/tertiary-proof-of-entitlement

Comment: I followed this link earlier as well but in the "Application for a Transport Concession Entitlement Card" (https://cec-apply.transport.nsw.gov.au/ApplyCEC/ApplyCEC.html), they are asking for NSW address

Comment: Punch in an ACT address and see what happens?

Comment: It didn't work. They aren't giving an option to select the states. It is there as NSW (fixed). Even though I entered NSW address where I'm gonna stay temporarily they say student details aren't valid.

Comment: @Mad Do you even need the CEC card? If you have approved student ID (list above), it's enough.  If you don't, ask your institution what to do.